# How are large binary trees built?

Tags: tree

This is a question that has been bothering me for years. I want to know how large binary trees are built, the only method I know is to create a function to push one element onto a tree(a function called insert();). If I have a 3 element tree and want to add 5 elements, I am going to have to call the insert function 5 times. This seems a pretty poor method, what if I want to add 50 elements? There has to be a better way than just calling the insert() function fifty times.

Comment: Do a quick google search for balancing binary trees to find things like the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).

Answer (score 9):

If the data is pre-sorted you can build it recursively.

Basically to build the tree for some input:

1. Create a new node
2. If the input is one entry only, the value of the node is that entry
3. Otherwise:

   1. In the left sub-tree of the node, place the tree built from the first half of the input
   2. In the right sub-tree of the node, place the tree built from the second half of the input

The third step will recursively apply itself to portions of the input.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
FUNCTION TREE (input -> node)
    IF input IS 1 ENTRY
        VALUE OF node IS entry OF input
    ELSE
        SPLIT input IN 2
        LEFT SUB-TREE OF node IS TREE(FIRST HALF OF input)
        RIGHT SUB-TREE OF node IS TREE(SECOND HALF OF input)
```

Here's some [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) C# code you can experiment with:

```
// Add the following two using-directives to LINQPad:
// System.Drawing
// System.Drawing.Imaging

static Bitmap _Dummy = new Bitmap(16, 16, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
static Font _Font = new Font("Arial", 12);

void Main()
{
    var sorted = Enumerable.Range(1, 16).ToArray();
    var tree = BuildTree(sorted);
    Visualize(tree);
}

public Node<T> BuildTree<T>(T[] input)
{
    return BuildTree<T>(input, 0, input.Length);
}

public Node<T> BuildTree<T>(T[] input, int left, int right)
{
    if (right <= left)
        return null;

    if (right == left + 1)
        return new Node<T> { Value = input[left] };

    int middle = (left + right) / 2;
    return new Node<T>
    {
        Left = BuildTree<T>(input, left, middle),
        Right = BuildTree<T>(input, middle, right)
    };
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public Node<T> Left;
    public Node<T> Right;

    public Bitmap ToBitmap()
    {
        Size valueSize;
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_Dummy))
        {
            var tempSize = g.MeasureString(Value.ToString(), _Font);
            valueSize = new Size((int)tempSize.Width + 4, (int)tempSize.Height + 4);
        }

        Bitmap bitmap;
        Color valueColor = Color.LightPink;
        if (Left == null && Right == null)
        {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(valueSize.Width, valueSize.Height);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                g.Clear(Color.White);
            valueColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            using (var leftBitmap = Left.ToBitmap())
            using (var rightBitmap = Right.ToBitmap())
            {
                int subNodeHeight = Math.Max(leftBitmap.Height, rightBitmap.Height);
                bitmap = new Bitmap(
                    leftBitmap.Width + rightBitmap.Width + valueSize.Width,
                    valueSize.Height + 32 + subNodeHeight);

                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                    int baseY  = valueSize.Height + 32;

                    int leftTop = baseY; // + (subNodeHeight - leftBitmap.Height) / 2;
                    g.DrawImage(leftBitmap, 0, leftTop);

                    int rightTop = baseY; // + (subNodeHeight - rightBitmap.Height) / 2;
                    g.DrawImage(rightBitmap, bitmap.Width - rightBitmap.Width, rightTop);

                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, bitmap.Width / 2 - 4, valueSize.Height, leftBitmap.Width / 2, leftTop);
                    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, bitmap.Width / 2 + 4, valueSize.Height, bitmap.Width - rightBitmap.Width / 2, rightTop);
                }
            }
        }

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            float x = (bitmap.Width - valueSize.Width) / 2;
            using (var b = new SolidBrush(valueColor))
                g.FillRectangle(b, x, 0, valueSize.Width - 1, valueSize.Height - 1);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, 0, valueSize.Width - 1, valueSize.Height - 1);
            if (Left == null && Right == null)
                g.DrawString(Value.ToString(), _Font, Brushes.Black, x + 1, 2);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}

void Visualize<T>(Node<T> node)
{
    node.ToBitmap().Dump();
}
```

Here's the output:

[image: LINQPad output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I gave you a +1 but I want to be fully convinced on how to do this before I award the bounty - which I'm not. I somewhat agree with the steps you have provided but your pseudocode does not match it. 'Create a new node', how can you create distinct nodes recursively, especially using a language like C/C++ where you must use pointers? In your pseudocode you are also not specifying how any tree is actually built which is really what I'm looking for. In your steps you say: "place the tree built from the first half", but how does this happen?

Comment: Also - In the C# code you provided, specifically the Build<T>(T[] input, int left, int right) function, where are the parameters of 'left' and 'right' coming from? It looks like they still need to be manually specified. If this is so, then I would still have to build up the tree manually instead of recursively - which defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: "input" is a sorted array of input. left starts out at 0, and right always starts out as the length of the array.

Comment: And I don't understand your comment about C/C++, you would of course allocate new Node objects/structs as needed, from the heap.

Answer (score 2):

There is. Knuth gives an algorithm for building a reasonably balanced binary from *sorted* input, in *ACP* volume III I think.

Comment: Guess now I even have more of areason to pick that book up